# How to define the uniform asymptotic negligibility assumption for moving-average process with random coeficients?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, uniform-convergence, self-learning, time-series

The uniform asymptotic negligibility (UAN) assumption is well know in probability theory. In my case, I have a definition of (UAN) for moving-average (MA) processes.

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ a sequence of MA processes:
$$X_{t;n}= \sum_{j =1}^n \psi_{j;n} \varepsilon_{t-j;n}, \quad (t \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N})$$
We say that $(X_n)_{n\geq 1}$ satisfyes UAN condtion if
\begin{equation}\tag{UAN}
    \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \underset{1\leq j \leq n}{\max} |\psi_{j;n}|=0
\end{equation}
It turns out that at a given moment, the coefficients $\psi_{j;n}$'s are random variables. So I would like to know how to adapt the UAN definition. My first attempt is:
\begin{equation}\tag{UAN 1}
    \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \underset{1\leq j \leq n}{\max} P( |\psi_{j;n}| > \epsilon )=0\quad (\forall \, \epsilon > 0)
\end{equation}

Another alternative is
\begin{equation}\tag{UAN 2}
    \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} P\big( \underset{1\leq j \leq n} {\max} |\psi_{j;n}| > \epsilon \big)=0\quad (\forall \, \epsilon > 0)
\end{equation}
Or maybe:
\begin{equation}\tag{UAN 3}
    P\big(\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \underset{1\leq j \leq n} {\max} |\psi_{j;n}| = 0 \big)=1
\end{equation}

Honestly, I'm quite confused on which definition would be the most appropriate.

Some reference, help!

Comment: (UAN3) => (UAN2) <=> (UAN1)

Comment: excellent! So are you suggest adopting the definition of  almost certainly uniform asymptotic negligibility , i.e., (UAN3)? Do you have some reference to show the implications/equivalence you gave?

Comment: Pls refer the paper: Helland, "CLT for martingales ... ", Scand. J. Statist, 9:79-94, (1982). Lemma 2.2.